# making jquery AJAX POST to resful API

Tags: rest, jquery

I'm trying to convert a REST call using Cordova plugin to a JQuery AJAX POST. I don't have the JQuery code right, the call is getting a connection refused error (hitting localhost).  I'm successfully making GET requests to my localhost, so there isn't a connectivity issue.

The REST API code:

```
@Path("/track")
public class TrackResource {  
   ...
```

The method in TrackResource class i'm trying to hit :

```
@POST
@Path("{trackid}")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response addToResource(@PathParam("trackid") String trackid, String bodyJson) {
```

The AJAX code:

```
var trackingJSON = JSON.stringify(tracking_data);
var urlAjax =  "http://localhost:7001/ds/resources/track/" + trackid;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urlAjax,
    data: trackingJSON,
    beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "Loading...", true) },
    complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg() },
    success: function(data) { alert("ajax worked"); },
    error: function(data) {alert("ajax error"); },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

I'm not sure if i'm using the data option in the ajax call correctly, but it's my understanding that is where you would put the data you want to pass server side.

I do have other GET calls to this same TrackResource class working, so i know the base part of the URL is correct.  I know the trackid value is populated correctly as well.

Comment: can you formulate the exact same POST you are trying to make with AJAX and POST it directly to the endpoint to see what happens? I really don't see any issue with the jQuery.

Comment: Yes, using firefox REST client i can make this post to my localhost.

Comment: I needed to use the contentType param and set it to application/json. However this did not resolve my connection issues.  I'm still getting a java.net.ConnectionException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use the router address of my computer, 192...., in order to hit my localhost...  I was running the application on an actual Android device, however, I guess trying to use localhost or 127.0.0.1 in the AJAX call must have been causing issues.

Answer (score 3):

If you're posting a JSON string make sure you also set `contentType: "application/json"`.

```
var trackingJSON = JSON.stringify(tracking_data);
var urlAjax =  "http://localhost:7001/ds/resources/track/" + trackid;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urlAjax,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: trackingJSON,
    beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "Loading...", true) },
    complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg() },
    success: function(data) { alert("ajax worked"); },
    error: function(data) {alert("ajax error"); },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer, and this worked when i hit my Dev server. Using your suggestion works perfectly when I hit my Dev server.  However, unfortunately I'm still having connectivity issues to my localhost, I get a connectivity exception.